# Correlation or comparison between two images

Tags: correlation

Anyone know any function to make a correlation between two images which are quite similar as can be an image of a lane with another image of a turning in C ++ channel have been researching and found something about subtraction and implement it but do not understand to do with the result of subtraction.
I hope someone can help me, you will thank a lot.

For example the following images are almost identical but they are not.
[image: Imagen1]

[image: Imagen 2]

Comment: Could you add some examples of pictures you want to compare? That would make it much easier to answer your question.

Comment: Now add two sample images @multitaskPro

Comment: Also these images the'm working with Hough and shows me the line of rail